# Automate posting to Pinterest with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, pinterest

I currently have a site that generates user-created images via php ImageMagick.   While we're all waiting for the arrival of the new Pinterest API,  is there a way to automate the posting of these user-created images to my own Pinterest account?

I'm looking for a way to not only autofill the form elements used by the PinIt button but to automatically submit the user-created images to my Pinterest account.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You can make requests from your script using `curl`.

Comment: This question can be ignored now that the Pinterest API is available.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this, it seems to do the job : https://github.com/kellan/pinterest.api.php/blob/master/pinterest.api.php

Comment: It's out dated now. As per GitHub

Comment: @dev_ramiz_1707 do you find any code?

Comment: @jimi-del Not yet, but do let me know if you have or find it.

Comment: Use  zapier instead script, May be that will help you for the same. @jimi-del